# I want to do data Imputation based on another dataframe in R

Tags: r

[image]

This is my dataset and i've created another dataset which has mean with respect to Item_Fat_Content,Item_Type Combination like 
[image]

I want to impute the missing values in Item_Weight in my dataset based on these mean values like

`aggregate(Dataset$Item_Weight~Dataset$Item_Fat_Content+Dataset$Item_Type,Dataset$Item_Fat_Content, mean ,na.action = na.omit)`

I'm having trouble imputing these mean values accordingly in my orginal dataset where Item_Weight values are missing.

Comment: Hi, Request you to please avoid pasting pictures  in your question, instead try using `dput` command and paste the data structure here, in that way people can replicate what is there on your system. Thanks : example: `dput(dataframe_name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some fake data:

```
x <- mtcars
rownames(x) <- NULL
```

Using `merge` later results in a reordering of the rows. To counter that (at least for this example), I add an `i` variable to keep track of the order. This may not be necessary for your use, and/or you already have something easily orderable in your data.

```
x$i <- seq_len(nrow(x))
```

Create some missing values:

```
x$mpg[c(1,3,5)] <- NA
head(x, n=10)
#     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  i
# 1    NA   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  1
# 2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  2
# 3    NA   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  3
# 4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1  4
# 5    NA   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2  5
# 6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1  6
# 7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4  7
# 8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2  8
# 9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2  9
# 10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 10
```

Let's create some categorized averages so that we can merge them back in. The `na.rm=TRUE` is passed to the `FUN` function (`mean`).

```
avgs <- aggregate(mpg ~ cyl + am, mean, na.rm = TRUE, data = x)
# the column name is the same, but we need it to be different for the merge
colnames(avgs)[3] <- "newmpg"
avgs
#   cyl am   newmpg
# 1   4  0 22.90000
# 2   6  0 19.12500
# 3   8  0 14.71818
# 4   4  1 28.82857
# 5   6  1 20.35000
# 6   8  1 15.40000
```

And now the imputation-by-merge:

```
newx <- merge(avgs, x, by = c("cyl", "am"), all.y = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
```

Now we choose the first non-`NA` of the two columns with a direct `ifelse`:

```
newx$mpg <- ifelse(is.na(newx$mpg), newx$newmpg, newx$mpg)
```

After cleaning up the no-longer-needed column `$newmpg`, we restore the previous order.

```
newx$newmpg <- NULL
newx <- newx[order(newx$i),]
head( newx, n=10 )
#    cyl am      mpg  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs gear carb  i
# 28   6  1 20.35000 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0    4    4  1
# 29   6  1 21.00000 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0    4    4  2
# 21   4  1 28.82857 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1    4    1  3
# 7    6  0 21.40000 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1    3    1  4
# 9    8  0 14.71818 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0    3    2  5
# 4    6  0 18.10000 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1    3    1  6
# 8    8  0 14.30000 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0    3    4  7
# 2    4  0 24.40000 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1    4    2  8
# 1    4  0 22.80000 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1    4    2  9
# 6    6  0 19.20000 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1    4    4 10
```